# ListBox HorizontalScrollbar doen't work WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I have a ListBox in winforms , C# application.
i need to add to the ListBox CheckBoxes in the code , and i need that HorizontalScrollbar will appear when there is a lot of CheckBoxes and the ListBox can't show them all.
I have placed the ListBox on the Window and set it's HorizontalScrollbar to be true. Also i have set the maximum height and width for the ListBox.But when i run the application , i can't see all the CheckBoxes...
can anyone help with that?

this the code for adding the checkboxes :

```
            listBox1.HorizontalScrollbar = true;
            this.groupBox_ChooseTCPipConfg.Controls.Add(listBox1);
            CheckBox chk1 = new CheckBox();
            chk1.Text = "chk1";
            chk1.Location = new Point(2, 2);
            listBox1.Controls.Add(chk1);
            CheckBox chk2 = new CheckBox();
            chk2.Text = "chk2";
            chk2.Location = new Point(2,22);
            listBox1.Controls.Add(chk2);
            CheckBox chk3 = new CheckBox();
            chk3.Text = "chk3";
            chk3.Location = new Point(2, 42);
            listBox1.Controls.Add(chk3);
            CheckBox chk4 = new CheckBox();
            chk4.Text = "chk4";
            chk4.Location = new Point(2, 62);
            listBox1.Controls.Add(chk4);
            CheckBox chk5 = new CheckBox();
            chk5.Text = "chk5";
            chk5.Location = new Point(2, 82);
            listBox1.Controls.Add(chk5);
            CheckBox chk6 = new CheckBox();
            chk6.Text = "chk6";
            chk6.Location = new Point(2, 102);
            listBox1.Controls.Add(chk1);
            CheckBox chk7 = new CheckBox();
            chk7.Text = "chk7";
            chk7.Location = new Point(2, 122);
            listBox1.Controls.Add(chk7);
            CheckBox chk8 = new CheckBox();
            chk8.Text = "chk8";
            chk8.Location = new Point(2, 142);
            listBox1.Controls.Add(chk8);
            CheckBox chk9 = new CheckBox();
            chk9.Text = "chk9";
            chk9.Location = new Point(2, 162);
            listBox1.Controls.Add(chk9);
            CheckBox chk10 = new CheckBox();
            chk10.Text = "chk10";
            chk10.Location = new Point(2,202);
            listBox1.Controls.Add(chk10);
```

when i run the application , i can only see the first 7 checkboxes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont' have `ListBox` scroll because you didn't add any items to it. You just place the `CheckBox` controls inside. Scroll appears oly if you will have to many items.

For such purposes use [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) control.

Here is how properties should be set for `FlowLayoutPanel`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting [ListBox.HorizontalExtent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.horizontalextent%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Do not forget to read Remarks on above msdn reference.